# Read inside a Tag using XPath Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Hye I am new to read XML File using Java my problem is that I have been trying to read an xml and between a specific tag I want to get the required data I am using XPath and my query is:

```
   String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@type='STRING']";
```

It works fine and my specific Tag to read from is:

```
   <ATTRIBUTE name="Description" type="STRING"> SOME TEXT </ATTRIBUTE>
```

But I want to read the data inside only these types of Tags so that my output should be:

```
  SOME TEXT
```

inside the tag!
can somebody help me how can I do this Please I am new to xml reading! Trying my best as:

```
  String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and ./type/text()='STRING']";
```

But it wont give me any output!
thanks in advance

My Code:

```
   DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = null;
try {

builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(
        new FileInputStream("c:\\y.xml"));

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

       String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description'and @type='STRING']";
   System.out.println(expression);
   NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 
}


} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
System.out.print(e);
}
```

There is a problem with my code cant figure out what!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me with the changed XPath to:

`"/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description'][@type='STRING']"`:

```
private static final String EXAMPLE_XML =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<ADOXML adoversion=\"Version 5.1\" username=\"kvarga\" database=\"adonisdb\" time=\"08:55\"   date=\"30.11.2013\" version=\"3.1\">" +
            "<MODELS>" +
                "<MODEL version=\"\" applib=\"ADONIS BPMS BP Library 5.1\" libtype=\"bp\" modeltype=\"Business process model\" name=\"Product development\" id=\"mod.25602\">" +
                    "<MODELATTRIBUTES>" +
                        "<ATTRIBUTE name=\"Version number\" type=\"STRING\"> </ATTRIBUTE>" +
                        "<ATTRIBUTE name=\"Author\" type=\"STRING\">kvarga</ATTRIBUTE>" +
                        "<ATTRIBUTE name=\"Description\" type=\"STRING\">I WANT THIS PARA 2</ATTRIBUTE>" +
                    "</MODELATTRIBUTES>" +
                "</MODEL>" +
            "</MODELS>" +
        "</ADOXML>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(EXAMPLE_XML.getBytes()));
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description'][@type='STRING']";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("###" + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + "###");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
###I WANT THIS PARA 2###
```

Comment: lols how could you say that even you are posting after reading the problem i have to read an xml file then want to get the data inside a tag lols

Comment: sorry, but I do not understand your comment. I do not have the XML you used, so I used an in memory example and your code. With the example everything works. Hence, maybe your XPath is not correct, regarding the XML Document you read in. If you like post the XML document as well. Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: want i am providing the xml

Comment: The XML or the XSD or the XML snipped which you expect to match your XPath.

Comment: i have posted my xml part

Comment: I removed the `@name='Description'and` from your _XPath_ expression and extracted some of the text inside `ATTRIBUTE` tags. Maybe you try this first with your code?

Comment: i need to get the text where Attribute name="Description" type="STRING"

Comment: try this XPath: _"/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description'][@type='STRING']"_ instead

Comment: Now my example should work as well if you like to copy / paste it into your IDE

Comment: I am going into wrong Tag what i should have to do is to:

     String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and @type='STRING']";

Using this and its bingo!

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned code works fine.

You can try other way also to get the text node -

```
String expression = "/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/MODELATTRIBUTES/ATTRIBUTE/text()";

NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.println(nodeList.item(0).getNodeValue());
```

Comment: dont know what do you mean